# Javascript accessible 'handle' for first parameter in socket.io's .on()?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Trying to build some kind of 'smart parser' for `socket.on('message', function(data) {})` so that I can do a 'switch/case' on the first parameter.  Is there some global handle for that parameter so that something like the following works?

```
socket.on(socket.token.name, function(data) {
  switch (socket.token.name) {
    case "table:dashboard":
      // do something with data
      break;
    case "table:monitor":
      // do something with data
      break;
   }
});
```

Any ideas? I've perused the socket.io docs, but haven't found any hints *yet*.  Or some other direction to implement the same idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole thing in a closure.

```
function getHandler(name) {
  return function(data) {
    switch (name) {
      case "table:dashboard":
        // do something with data
        break;
      case "table:monitor":
        // do something with data
        break;
     }
  }
}

socket.on("foo", getHandler("foo"));
socket.on("bar", getHandler("bar"));
```

More optimally though, you would return a different function once, instead of having the switch-case run every time.

```
function getHandler(name) {
  switch (name) {
    case "table:dashboard":
      return function(data) {}
      break;
    case "table:monitor":
      return function(data) {}
      break;
   }
}
```

Alternatively, just bind a second argument to your handler:

```
socket.on("table:dashboard", handler.bind(handler, "table:dashboard"))

function handler(name, data) {
  switch (name) {
    case "table:dashboard":
      // do something with data
      break;
    case "table:monitor":
      // do something with data
      break;
   }
});
```

Comment: `socket.on("foo", getHandler("foo"));` (or your handler.bind alternative) just looks repetitive - was not keen on having to repeat "foo", and I didn't want to have to care about the handler name... just programmatically parse the handler (let's me filter out bad names too).  Would prefer to parse *whatever* the event handler name is directly when it comes into the client.  

But ok, I can see that providing a single handler name, then parsing some unique identifier *inside the data* is probably the better way to go anyway (as discussed in the Javascript chat).  Thanks for the insight!  :)